# Cron Daemon Missing

Tags: cron

I am scheduling scripts in cron and am facing this problem. I try to check if cron daemon is running with

`service crond status`

and it returns

`Missing SERVICE_URI environment variable`

What does it mean and how do I overcome this situation?

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand this.
When I run "ps -ef | grep crond" , it gives me 
root      4147     1  0 Oct23 ?        00:00:04 crond
user 32670 32357  0 06:12 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto crond

Honesty, I don't understand whats happening here

Comment: What type of Unix or Linux are you using, and what is its version?

Comment: Linux version 4.9.184-0.1.ac.235.83.329.metal1.x86_64 (mockbuild@koji-pdx-corp-builder-60004) (gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2) (GCC) )